# php form errors

Tags: php, mysql

hello im trying to set custom errors. i got a form. actions to post.php i dont want form to go post.php for errors i need to set errors in same page. i tried

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO yazilar (baslik, spot, spot_kisa, spot_resim, spot_resim_isim, icerik, kategori, tiklanma, eklemetarihi)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[baslik]','$_POST[spot]','$_POST[spot_kisa]','$_POST[spot_resim]','$_POST[spot_resim_isim]','$_POST[icerik]','$_POST[kategori]','$_POST[tiklanma]','$_POST[tarih]')
";
$sonuc = mysql_query($sql);

<?
    if ($sonuc) {
        echo ("<p class='msg done'>Yeni icerik basarili bir sekilde eklendi.</p>");
    } 
    if(! $sonuc) {
        echo ("<p class='msg warning'>Ekleme basarisiz oldu.</p>");  
    }
?>
```

this always shows Yeni icerik basarili bir sekilde eklendi.

this.

help me plx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to have your errors show up in the submitting form just move your post.php code into your form page and condition it like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['baslik'])) {
  $sql = "
    INSERT INTO yazilar (baslik, spot, spot_kisa, spot_resim, spot_resim_isim, icerik, kategori, tiklanma, eklemetarihi)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[baslik]','$_POST[spot]','$_POST[spot_kisa]','$_POST[spot_resim]','$_POST[spot_resim_isim]','$_POST[icerik]','$_POST[kategori]','$_POST[tiklanma]','$_POST[tarih]')
";
  $sonuc = mysql_query($sql);

  if ($sonuc) {
    echo ("<p class='msg done'>Yeni icerik basarili bir sekilde eklendi.</p>");
    exit;
  } 
  else {
    $error = "<p class='msg warning'>Ekleme basarisiz oldu.</p>";  
  }
}
?>

// form code here
<?php if(isset($error)) { echo $error; } ?>
// around where you'd like the error to display
```

Now if the action is a success the success message will display with nothing else, otherwise the form will be redisplayed with the error message where you positioned it.  Also, please see soulmerge's comments on SQL injection, it's a serious security risk that can be easily avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is valid and it inserts data sucsesfully, therefore `MySql_Query()` returns true, which in turn "triggers" the first `if`, but not the second.

See documentation for [return values of MySql_Query](http://www.php.net/mysql_query).

If you want validation you have to write it.

also: your two if statements can be refactored into one. Look at the [if/else](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php) syntax

Comment: You have to write it then. It doesn't just magically happen :)

Comment: That's a different question so open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $sonuc = mysql_query($sql);

    <?php
       if($sonuc !== false){
          echo ("<p class='msg done'>Yeni icerik basarili bir sekilde eklendi.</p>");
       } else {
          echo ("<p class='msg warning'>Ekleme basarisiz oldu.</p>");     
       }
    ?>
```

EDIT: When you need a validation instead of a check if the query worked check this http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/form-validation-using-php.aspx

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$sonuc = mysql_query($sql);
```

with this

```
$sonuc = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

is there any errors?

is it possible that your table fields do not match that ones you insert?

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong about it? The [return values of `mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#function.mysql-query.returnvalues) is a boolen for INSERT queries, which is `true` if the operation was successful. Have you tried inserting invalid values (like a text that is too long)? That should generate a warning and return false.

But what bothers much more is that your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-Injection). Please read up on [sql injections on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) how to fix that problem.

Comment: What are you inserting that you think should generate an error?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
    if ($sonuc !== false){...
See [php manual entry](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score -1):

Jan Hančič has already answered the question but as a side note:

Don't use POST data directly on your queries it will end badly trust me!!